# Bootstrap sidebar code

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I never really coded anything with CSS. I've overrided some bootstrap CSS for containers (container-two is for menu, container is for the rest). Also, there is some custom CSS. I've copied it all here: http://paste.laravel.com/JIy.

How could I make a sidebar on the right/left side (easy configurable) in a well. I've tried several things with margins but they don't do the trick. Something like little  boxes. Could anyone provide the example or something? You can also view my master/base layout: http://paste.laravel.com/JIz

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post an isolated example of your problem? And maybe a fiddle demo?

Comment: I've put your code in jsFiddle, and it looks like your sidebars are already in [wells](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#misc)? Unless I'm missing something?  
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sqDrR/3/  
Result: http://jsfiddle.net/sqDrR/3/embedded/result/

Comment: @seren01 yeah, they are, it's coded in laravel so I forgot to include my main part of the layout... here's the view source in html.. I want the sidebars be on the left or the right.. they are below - http://paste.laravel.com/JIY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to override Bootstrap's `container`, you should probably use Bootstrap's `container-fluid` instead (right below container in [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts)). This allows you to do:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Posts content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to have the sidebars on the left, or:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Posts content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to have the sidebars on the right. You can change the number of `<div class="span#"></div>`'s to have as many sections in a row that you need.

Comment: http://paste.laravel.com/JJE this doesn't look so good... http://1.imgland.net/WCgdEQ.png, also how could I make the width smaller..

Comment: Firstly, you have a span that isn't closed correctly in your code (I added a comment where this was happening in the jsFiddle) which is messing a lot of things up. Secondly, your divs aren't opened/closed  at the correct spots, which is causing the posts inside of posts.

I deleted everything but one post and the sidebar in a jsFiddle.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sqDrR/9/
Result: http://jsfiddle.net/sqDrR/9/embedded/result/

Also, to change the width of the sections, change span10 to span[some other number there is a limit at like 12 or 15].

Comment: Aah. There's to much code, I'm coding in Laravel.. I can't find myself in this. Could you please just fix my div's here? http://paste.laravel.com/JKo

Comment: @core_m I don't actually know php, and as an Answer-er on StackOverflow, it's my job to suggest solutions, but not clean up other people's code. Sorry :(